# Buying Video Card for 1600x900 monitor?

Tags: windows-xp, video, graphics-card

I just bought a monitor for a relative's computer (Intel 82915G chipset) which should produce 1600x900. Though the current card can produce 1600x1200, there's no way (that I know of) to force it to produce 1600x900.

Assuming buying a card would be a solution, how would one find a cheap video card that can do 1600x900? They don't seem to list the modes in most ads.

If I'm missing something in Windows, please let me know, but I've looked around quite a bit and tried many things (including unsupported resolutions, etc).

Answer (score 4):

Generally speaking, any recent video card from nVidia, ATI, Intel, or another major manufacturer will support any resolution the monitor marks as displayable. Usually there are a set list of common resolutions which the monitor supports, up to it's native resolution. Here is a list of common video resolutions:

[image]

1600x900 is an odd resolution, and won't be displayed in any configuration panel unless it's the screen's maximum / native resolution. Out of curiosity, what monitor are you using?

If the monitor does not have a native resolution of 1600x900, you can try to [force an arbitrary resolution](http://www.mp3car.com/vbulletin/lcd-display/42122-tutorial-forcing-custom-resolution-windows.html). However, be warned that running LCD displays at anything other than their native resolution generally looks horrible. Supported resolutions aren't put in ads for graphics cards because only the maximum resolution is dependent on the graphics card, and it should be good to display any resolution less than that (Most consumer cards from ATI/nVidia will support up to WQXGA per display given a dual-link DVI cable or similar).

Comment: Thanks for that. It's an Acer h*h (is globbing ok, since I forget the model) 20" $100-at-best-buy monitor.

Comment: @Yar I highly doubt best-buy would sell a monitor with that resolution, or that Acer would make a consumer model with that resolution. Now I'm curious why you want to use that resolution :P

Comment: You can doubt it, but "highly?" It's an Acer H203H. Native res: 1600x900. Please see it here http://www.amazon.com/Acer-H203H-Bbmd-Widescreen-Monitor/dp/B003M64WRQ

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't able to find it - Thanks for the link, certainly an oddity by standards. It was kinda like you had just told me that you bought a car with 5 wheels. Anyways, what resolutions does the system allow you to choose with the monitor?

Comment: I don't get informed here unless you `@yar` me. You get informed anyway, since it's your answer. Closest resolution is 1600x1200... anyway, will hopefully be trying another video card today. Note: 16:9 and 1600x900 may have something in common. Let's see what happens. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Hooray! I have found a cure for this problem.
I have an optiplex gx280 with the same chipset, Intel(R) 82915G/GV/910GL.
Windows XP pro
I also have an Acer X203H 1600x900 monitor that was not able to achieve this resolution.

You can solve this dilemma by using an awesome software called Powerstrip. Can be found  here http://entechtaiwan.com/util/ps.shtm

Follow the instructions here
http://forums.entechtaiwan.com/index.php?topic=24.0

Hooray! Resolution desired has been acquired.

HINT:I hooked up this monitor to a PC that worked with it and took a screen shot of the working monitor stats to enter into the non-working pc.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the newer video cards support all standard monitor resolutions. NVIDIA and ATI brand cards come with software suites that allow you to specify resolutions if they are not available via Windows. Newegg.com sells all kinds of video cards and you should be able to find a good card for pretty cheap there.

Comment: not sure if it's against the rules here, but can you suggest any specific cards that you know will work?

Comment: I'll second TheDudeAbides, most video cards do that - including integrated video solutions from Intel, ATI and nVidia. However, you will often need to install a card-specific driver from the manufacturer instead of a generic Microsoft-provided video driver.

Comment: @chronos and TheDude, is it possible that an older (2007) video card will NOT do this native res? It recognizes the Acer monitor.